# avg value from a sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL table called `track_e_exercises` where is stored attempts in a test, every row is a new attempt. I want to know how to obtain the avg attempts in the course per person. How can I make that?
`c_id` is the course id column and `exe_user_id` is the user id column.

[image]

expected result for c_id=7 => (# of attempts in the course/peopple that attempted) = 1
expected result for c_id=8 => avg attempts = 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select c_id, count(*) / count(distinct exe_user_id) as avg_attempts
from t
group by c_id;
```